# Which are better of these two pairs

Tags: strategy, material-balance

Which give me more advantage two Knights or two Bishops ?. And what should I choose two Rooks or a Queen ?

Comment: I am quite sure that 2 Rooks are better than a Queen, 10 vs 9 ?

Comment: No. Sometimes a queen is better than 2 rooks, such as if there are no open files. A strong player used to win games in which he had a queen and gave his opponent 2 rooks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*On average*, two bishops are better than two knights, but there are plenty of exceptions (e.g., a closed position where the bishops don't have room to operate).

*On average*, two rooks are better than a queen, but there are plenty of exceptions (e.g., when the player with the rooks has a bunch of weak pawns that are easy for the queen to attack).

Comment: I totally agree with you : D

Comment: I once heard a grandmaster say that you should not play chess as a bookkeeper. All depends on the position.

Answer (score 5):

Read the article "Evaluation of Material Imbalances" by GM Larry Kaufman:
[The Evaluation of Material Imbalances](http://home.comcast.net/~danheisman/Articles/evaluation_of_material_imbalance.htm).

He says about the bishop pair:

> The bishop pair has an average value of half a pawn (more when the
>   opponent has no minor pieces to exchange for one of the bishops),
>   enough to regard it as part of the material evaluation of the
>   position, and enough to overwhelm most positional considerations.
>   Moreover, this substantial bishop pair value holds up in all
>   situations tested, regardless of what else is on the board. This large
>   a bishop pair value is surprising because in the opening grandmasters
>   will often give up the bishop pair to double the opponent's pawns or
>   to gain a mild lead in development, factors which are generally not
>   worth half a pawn [DH: Since at the very start of the game a tempo is
>   worth roughly a third of a pawn - and more later! - it is worth losing
>   a tempo to save the bishop pair, but if you can gain two tempo by
>   giving up the bishop pair that may be worth it in the short run!]

Later, queen vs. two rooks:

> Although many authors talk about queen and pawn equaling two rooks,
>   this is only close to true with no minor pieces on the board; with two
>   or more minors each, the queen needs no pawns to equal the rooks. I
>   recall a famous Portisch-Fischer game in which Portisch "won" two
>   rooks for Fischer's queen right out of the opening, but Fischer soon
>   won a weak pawn and went on to win rather easily, despite the nominal
>   point equality. In fact Fischer's annotations severely criticized
>   Portisch for making the trade; Fischer understood very well that with
>   lots of material on the board, the queen is every bit as good as the
>   rooks, so once he won a pawn he was effectively a full pawn ahead.

His basic tables of values is:

- Pawn = 1
- Bishop pair = +½
- Rook =  5
- Bishop = 3¼
- Knight =  3¼
- Queen =  9¾